# Magento 2.4 - Express Checkout - Shipping Address Error

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

A fresh install Magento 2.4.x + theme, but having some issue related to express checkout, as seen from below picture on red-box area.

[image]

The form has missing some elements, like firstname, lastname etc.
When I compare things around, it should have it. Do I miss some setup?

Also, when I check on console, I've seen some javascript error that I'm not familiar with, as below

*edit - one additional error that I forgot to add

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return oscAddress.fieldAfterRender(element.dataScope) }"
Message: oscAddress is not defined
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return { data:elems,as:'element'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return element.visible() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return (element.input_type =='checkbox'|| element.input_type =='radio') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return $parent.fieldTemplate }"
Message: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return oscAddress.fieldAfterRender(element.dataScope) }"
Message: oscAddress is not defined
```

I'm not really familiar with front-end stack on Magento, so I don't know what I need to do.

Any suggestion? Do I miss some server / code setup? or maybe Admin setup?
I already tried to refresh cache etc, but the problem still remains.
Also, I already change to **Luma** / default theme, but the problem still persist. So, I'm wondering if there's something that I missed.

PS - I already fulfill the requirements to install Magento, like, PHP version, elasticsearch version, etc, as-per documentation. So, I'm wondering if there's something that I missed out.

Thanks. :)

Comment: did you run all commands like compile, static-content deploy etc?

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi - yes, I do run all of it after installing it, there are - php bin/magento indexer:reindex | php bin/magento setup:upgrade | php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f | php bin/magento cache:flush --- do I missed some commands?

Comment: I think those are enough but can also try` setup:di:compile`. And if it is on local, check if all Magento folder rights are given.

Comment: Hi @AbdulSamadAbbasi - thanks for your suggestion, but the issue still persist. Not sure why.

Comment: The error is from onestepcheckout extension.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - sorry for my late replies - so, it's not a part of magento default (base code as like a fresh install)?

Comment: @wandyyd yes, if you disable the onestepcheckout extension and check, then you are able to place order.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - thanks for letting me know! I did a fresh install and do check step-by-step when installing & setup theme, seems there's some conflict / incorrect data that theme has inserted when I install the theme. Now it's clear and good so far.